# Is there a standard format for pre-departure clearances?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-operations, pre-clearance

I am curious to know, from current airline pilots, if the formatting - and therefore reliability and ease of use - of pre-departure clearances (PDC's) has improved since they were first introduced?

Back then we would see [differing formats, incorrect flight numbers and routings](http://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/publications/directline/dl5_pdc.htm), and the like.  ATC would send them to the company and then the company would give them to the flight crew together with other relevant documents.

I'm sure that the process has greatly improved since those days, but I'd like to know if PDCs have now been standardized?

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about PDCs, but it does seem that they are now standardized. One aircrew training site [said in April 2014](https://www.aircrewacademy.com/follow-the-agonic-line/313-finally-pdc):

> For those of you capable of receiving a Predeparture Clearance (PDC),
>   have you noticed a change since the first week of April? The FAA
>   changed the way it issues PDCs. Gone are the days of trying to decide
>   if you got a reroute in the PDC. The FAA recognized there was a
>   problem with standardization with regards to reroutes

The article points to [JO 7110.113](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/2015-04-13_JO_7110_113E_Final.pdf), *Procedures for Issuing Automated Clearances*, which says:

> **5. Explanation of Policy Changes.** This order is revised to provide standardization of PDC clearances across the FAA.

I guess you can read the rest of the JO for more information, it means nothing to me :-)